# how to determine if a .net app is a "core" app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I need to update a new .NET app and I think it was mentioned that it was .NET Core.  How can I examine the solution properties to determine if it is in fact a "core" app?

The web project has a System.Core reference but I googled this and it seems that System.Core.dll has been a part of the .NET framework since  at least .NET f/w 3.5.

The app has a package.json file but the existence of that file in a sln does not necessarily guarantee that the app is a .NET core app.  I've also read that a .NET core app can run on different .NET framework versions.

So how can I determine if a .NET app is indeed a "Core" app? In other words, what makes a Core app a Core app?

Comment: The whole .net framework should be Backward Compatible. Do you mean **how to determine whether one .net app depends on third party libraries**?

Answer (score 11):

#### Updated for .NET Core >= 2.x and/or VS2017

In VS2017 .NET Core projects use the .csproj structure again.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreappx.y</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

or

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandardx.y</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

#### Old Answer for .NET Core 1.x and VS2015

There are some indicators to it.

The existence `project.json` suggest it's one of the newer project forms (be aware though that `project.json` will go away with .NET Core/.NET Core Tools for VS with Version 1.1).

Inside it, you'll have a frameworks section, like

```
"frameworks": {
  "net45": {
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
      "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0"
    }
  },
  "netstandard1.0": {
    "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ],
    "dependencies": {
    }
  },
  "netstandard1.3": {
    "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ],
    "dependencies": {
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters": "4.0.0-rc3-24212-01"
    }
  }
}
```

In case of applications (ASP.NET Core Web Project or new project.json based console applications), `netstandard1.x` will be named `netcoreapp1.0`.

If there is more than one entry, the application or library targets multiple platforms (and will build multiple binary files in separate folders).

**Update**

Of course I forgot another indicator. .NET Core application do reference `Microsoft.NETCore.App` (either as `"type": "platform"` for portable apps or without it for self-contained apps). `netstandard1.x` (class libraries) do reference `NETStandard.Library`.

.NET Core applications are based on `System.Runtime` which is a part of .NET Framework 4.5 and newer and used for Windows (and Windows Phone) 8.0/8.1/10 applications, hence `portable-net45+win81` packages are compatible with .NET Core too.

That being said, ASP.NET Core is a webstack which can run on both, full .NET Framework (4.5 or higher) and on .NET Core. So just having a ASP.NET Core application do not tell much about the platform it aims.

Comment: Do you have some reference to read about removeal of `project.json`? Can only find stuff from May and it's still here :) In the .net core 1.1 announcement they only say it's a new structure of project.json https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/25/announcing-net-core-1-1-preview-1/

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/ Dunno if they change their mind to postpone it to a later point, but the goal is to move to a msbuild compatible projectstructure (like csproj) to simplify the build pipeline and be able to use the existing building infrastructure. But its more related to the .NET Core Tools for Visual Studio rather than to the framework itself. iirc the goal is that existing projects get converted automatically. also see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/19/net-core-tooling-in-visual-studio-15/

Comment: Seems they like changing stuff back and forth all the time :)

Comment: moving to msbuild was announced long ago, even before it went RTM and scheduled for the final tooling version (the tooling are still in preview phase and scheduled to be released as final together with VS 15)

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy to determine Asp.net Core application.

There are some identifiers to it.
There are few file in a project that helps to determine Core Project

Files like

- project.json
- appsetting.json
- startup.cs

Inside project.json, it include

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Here by `dependencies` one can determine about the type of project..NET Core application do reference Microsoft.NETCore.App (either as "type": "platform" for portable apps or without it for self-contained apps).

Asp.net Core Application are platform independent, So a ASP.NET Core application do not express much about the platform .

Comment: instead of "project.json" do you mean "package.json"?

Comment: No its project.json,which is included in all Asp.net Core projects